# Write binary asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, streamwriter, binary-data

I am trying to make an old method asynchronous.
It takes the BLOB from the database and writes it to the disk as a file.

However, there is no async version of the write method of the `BinaryWriter`.
Can I use the `StreamWriter` instead? Because it has the `WriteAsync` method.
What are the differences? Any disadvantages?

Partial code:

```cs
OracleParameter returnParam = new OracleParameter("blob", OracleDbType.Blob);
command.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

OracleBlob blob = returnParam.Value as OracleBlob;

byte[] data = new byte[blob.Length];

await blob.ReadAsync(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(blob.Length));

fileFullPath = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        bw.Write(data); //NO ASYNC METHOD HERE
        logger.Debug("Finished writing file {0} to disk", fileFullPath);
    }
}
```

Can I change it to the following?

```cs
OracleParameter returnParam = new OracleParameter("blob", OracleDbType.Blob);
command.Parameters.Add(returnParam);

await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

OracleBlob blob = returnParam.Value as OracleBlob;

byte[] data = new byte[blob.Length];

await blob.ReadAsync(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(blob.Length));

fileFullPath = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(new UnicodeEncoding().GetChars(data)); // HAD TO CONVERT THE BYTE ARRAY INTO A CHAR ARRAY
        logger.Debug("Finished writing file {0} to disk", fileFullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always look into the docs to find the info you want: [`BinaryWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.8) [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If you are on .NET Core you may consider [File.WriteAllBytesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytesasync?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `HAD TO CONVERT THE BYTE ARRAY INTO A CHAR ARRAY` - you realise they are completely different, don't you? Does your blob contain text encoded in UTF-16 and nothing except that?

Comment: P.S. _"Implements a **TextWriter for writing characters** to a stream in a particular encoding."_ (emphasis by me) - so it (StreamWriter) is certainly _not_ the best choice for writing blobs.

Comment: @GSerg, I wasn't aware that the arrays will be completely different in terms of encoding. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @KWC Then please absolutely see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BinaryWriter is unnecessary here.  Just [WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.writeasync?view=netframework-4.8) the `byte[]` to the stream

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
   await fs.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
   logger.Debug("Finished writing file {0} to disk", fileFullPath);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

> It takes the BLOB from the database and writes it to the disk as a file.

Usually, that should not be necessary. If you are writing a server, you could hand it out via a [HTTP handler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307985/info-asp-net-http-modules-and-http-handlers-overview) or whatever the equivalent is.

If this is more of a Download operation, you need the minimum amount of multitasking:

Throwing a lot of Tasks at it, is not going to help. This operation sounds like it is either Network- (Database) or Diskbound. All you can do with those is moving the whole read/write process into a single alternate task. That way the execution does not tie up the GUI. That is the minimum amount of multitasking, the one you have to do even when writing a Word Processor nowadays.

There is also useful information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#dont-block-await-instead

You could just move the whole code into an async function. 
Make sure that function returns a Task, even if it is the [one without result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task). Then you call it, and then await it.

Comment: I was not going to post an answer. The code you've added won't compile, because of the `static Task DownloadToDisk (DbCommand command)` line - which is ironically the only difference between that code and the OP's code. It was specifically the OP's question how to perform `bw.Write(data)` in an async way. If you were going to suggest to keep it synchronous but make sure the entire thing executes on its own thread with `Task.Run()`, then you could have simply said so, because the text before the code block does look completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @GSerg "It was specifically the OP's question how to perform bw.Write(data) in an async way." And I told him that is unessesary, he should just make the whole process a single Async Task. Making substeps async is not going to help at all.

Comment: Marking the method `async` will not magically make it non-blocking. If you have a blocking call there, it will block. `bw.Write()` is a blocking call. Unless the proposed `static Task DownloadToDisk()` (which needs to be `static async Task` in order for it to compile) is called with `Task.Run()`, or executes under a non-capturing synchronization context, it will block the calling thread.

Comment: @GSerg Okay, I removed the code. I guess your issue will now be that I removed the code?